# WordPress Theme Twenty Sixteen is Responsive. How Did They Do This Without Using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

It was said in its description

"It has custom color options with beautiful default color schemes, a harmonious fluid grid using a mobile-first approach, and impeccable polish in every detail. Twenty Sixteen will make your WordPress look beautiful everywhere."

There is nothing that suggests how they achieve this in the documentation..

Comment: You don't need bootstrap for making any theme or website responsive. You can achieve it using Media Queries. You can learn about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: @SimrandeepSingh How do you use hamburger/collapsible menu with a responsive website?

Comment: Hamburger icon can be shown on mobile screens using media queries and using jQuery or CSS it can be put into work

Comment: Ok thank you. so you don't really need bootstrap but if you need responsiveness quickly in one package it fits the bill..that's what I understand

Comment: Yes, you don't really need bootstrap but it helps you work quickly

Comment: you can create any rules and columns that you want with css

Answer (score 0):

They have used the media query for this check the path /wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css

and for color scheme change open the customize option under Appearance->customize
wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwordpress_demo%2Fwp-admin%2Ftheme-editor.php

The site can be responsive without used of boostrap with block HTML you can add you own class and you can make it responsive with media query